# Update python version to 3.10 and remove python 3.8

Tags: apt, 20.04, python

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 which comes with Python 3.8. I want to install Python 3.10 AND remove Python 3.8 because I lack disk space. I know how to install Python 3.10, but I am afraid that I will break my system once I remove Python 3.8.

FYI, I plan to use these commands to do it (ofc I run everything as root user):

```
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt install -y python3.10
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 2
update-alternatives --config python3 #then select python3.10
#found the above from https://www.itsupportwale.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-10-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-20-04-lts/
#my own code below
apt autoremove python3.8
```

Is that proper way of replacing Python 3.8 with Python 3.10? Thx :)

P.S. I installed a bunch of Python 3.8 "plugins" (sorry that is what I like to call) like `python3.8-venv`, I also want to remove them if unusable (I am not sure about that so I did not include this in my code above).

Comment: Many Ubuntu tools for 20.04 will only work with the default python3 (ie. 3.8), so I assume you've looked into this & have worked out that you won't be able to use any of those features in your modified system & thus will not be impacted on your Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system.  We cannot know the impacts on features (we don't even know if you're asking about desktop or server install; I assume server given it has fewer impacts) but consequences will impact your system; how severe depends on how you use it.

Comment: Do you have a *specific* REASON to go for the newer Python?

Comment: Answering everything, it all started with an apt package which depends python 3.10. Then, I figured out that I have only 2GB remaining (I would like to keep some space). Therefore, I am forces to remove python 3.8 after installing 3.10. Seeing all your comments, I will not remove python 3.8 and install python 3.10 on my main system. Instead, I also have a computer running Debian Buster (running python 3.6 but i think the procedure will still be same) as my testing system. Maybe I will test there, and I won't really care if something goes wrong. I will tell everyone does it work in Debian. :)

Comment: The package that *depends* on python 3.10 was obviously built for a newer release than you're using, my Debian desktop (*bookworm*) uses the same python 3.10.4 my current Ubuntu system uses; however Debian is off-topic here. Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  Debian will be less impacted, but you'll still have to check what relies on it as tools/programs may not work correctly meaning data corruption..

Comment: However, why is it available on focal? Like some packages are only on impish.

Comment: Exactly. It screwed up my machine so bad that I did a reinstall. So, can I just install python3.10 but don't remove python3.8 and use python3.10 as default via `update-alternatives`?

Comment: Btw, just noticed the installed size is 20MB lol. I can afford it.

Answer (score 5):

**DON'T!**

Removing the Python version that comes with your system is very likely to break it. Instead set up dedicated python environments for different versions.

Alternatively, update to Ubuntu 22.04 that comes with Python 3.10.4. As of today, it is only a week before final release.

Comment: I will not do that on my main system. Just in case I screw things up. But I will have a try on my secondary system.

Comment: Unfortunately AWS is is still on 3.9 so you are going to likely bump into issues using it.https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6886#issuecomment-1105497793